# Unable to DELETE or GET couchdb2 databases

Tags: database, couchdb, internal-server-error, couchdb-2.0

I have a testing script that creates and deletes testing databases. At some point today it started failing. Digging further it looks like several of my testing databases are in an inconsistent state.

The databases appear in Fauxton with the message "This database failed to load." I am unable to view the database contents on this interface. Their names which are usually links are now plain text.

Issuing GET and DELETE commands with curl shows the following errors:

```
$ curl -s -X DELETE http://username:password@0.0.0.0:5984/dbname
{"error":"error","reason":"internal_server_error"}

$ curl -s -X GET http://username:password@0.0.0.0:5984/dbname
{"error":"internal_server_error","reason":"No DB shards could be opened.","ref":2413987899}
```

I have looked inside the couchdb2 data directory and I do see that shards exist for these databases.

What can I do to delete these databases? I am not sure if I can do this by manually deleting files in the couchdb2 data directory.

Comment: What do your logs show?

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your issue yet? I had this same problem, and ultimately ended up just installing a new CouchDB 2.1.0 instance and replicating to it before taking down the original. I suspect it might have had something to do with CouchDB not liking its default choice of "couchdb@localhost" as the name for a node, because it was constantly telling me that was an illegal hostname.

Comment: I ended up blowing away my whole CouchDB docker instance and rebuilding it :[